# Can I resolve tree conflict with status 'missing' in SVN not manually?

Tags: svn, conflict

I merged two branches and have some tree conflicts.
Some directories and files, existed in one branch and not existed in other was not created in working copy after merge and stays in tree conflict. Can I say to TortoiseSVN to add files to my working copy and not add in manually?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way in Tortoise. But basically, if you need to instruct this to SVN (if you have command line client)

```
  svn resolve --accept theirs-full -R BASE_DIR

-R: recursive resolve for directories
-accept theirs-full: accept the changed done is the branch where you are merging from
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html

Answer (score 0):

Try first to merge the revisions those file were created in, then the ones you originally wanted to merge. This should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem; I resolved this by:

1. Performing a reverse merge on the affected revisions. I simply looked at the svn log for the conflicting folder and reverse merged all of the revisions. This reported tree conflicts once again. I accepted the only option that is present: 'accept working copy.'
2. I then performed the merge again. No tree conflicts were reported.

A late reply, but perhaps still useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following to resolve this issue

1. Revert
2. SVN Update

Answer (score -1):

The following steps fixed the issue.

Resolve

Clean

Commit